# Replacing specific lines throughout a long text file

Tags: notepad++

Like the title suggests i want help with quickly replacing numbers from a long text file that come after a specific line of words

(to be more specific im trying to modify some game files)

Example:

```
build_time = 730
```

and i want to replace it with

```
build_time = 1
```

But the problem is i dont know how to do this , and this type of line repeates itself randomly thruout the text document with random 3-digit ,2-digit and even 4 digit numbers

Note that i do NOT want to replace the words or move them in the document, just the number that comes after such line of text

Is there a way i can use notepad++ to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in Notepad++ using the find and replace tool mixed with regular expressions.

For example, use `build_time = \d+` as the Find and use `build_time = 1` as the replace.

Make sure your search mode is set to `Regular Expression`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @TheGrandKnjaz If this helped you out, please accept the answer to help people in the future! :)